# How to solve react native null value in picker?

Tags: android, react-native, view, dropdown

I've been working on a react native application on the Android Platform. I implemented a DropDown picker but it gives an error.

The code piece that gives the error:

```
<View style={styles.if_filterbox}>
    <View style={{ alignSelf: 'center', paddingTop: 5 }}>
        <Text style={styles.if_formLabel}>Adres Seçiniz</Text>
    </View>


    <View style={{ flex: 1, flexDirection: 'column' }}>
        <View style={{ flex: 0.5, flexDirection: 'row' }}>


        <View style={styles.if_regionselect}>
            <Picker
            selectedValue={this.state.cityID}
            style={styles.if_picker}
            mode="dropdown"
            onValueChange={(itemValue, itemIndex) => {
                if (itemValue !== 0) {
                this.setState({
                    city: this.state.cities[itemValue],
                })
                }
            }
            }>
            {this.checkIsCitySelected()}
            {Object.keys(this.state.cities).map(key => {
                return <Picker.Item label={this.state.cities[key].isim} value={key} />
            })}
            </Picker>
        </View>
        </View>
    </View>
</View>  

checkIsCitySelected = () => {
    if (this.state.cityID >= 0) {
      return (<Picker.Item label={this.state.city["isim"]} value={this.state.cityID} />)
    } else {
      return (<Picker.Item label='Şehir Seçiniz' value='-1' />)
    }
  }
```

I know that cities array is not empty.

Error:
[Android Dropdown Error](https://i.ibb.co/SPwdLWj/android-ss.png)

Comment: Welcome to the community! I don't really understand what your question is. Maybe you could explain which error you are getting and from which line that is?

Comment: Thank you. In the code I want to load a list of cities into the Picker. However mapping cities to the Picker Item gives the error.  It gives the error message: while updating property “items” of a view managed by AndroidDropdownPicker

Answer (score 1):

I solved the problem. In the picker, the value was "key". I changed the value to the city id. In this case city id is: `this.state.cities[key].sehir_no`

The code block changed to

```
<View style={styles.if_regionselect}>
    <Picker
    selectedValue={this.state.cityID}
    style={styles.if_picker}
    mode="dropdown"
    onValueChange={(itemValue, itemIndex) => {
        if (itemValue !== 0) {
        this.setState({
            city: this.state.cities[itemValue],
            cityID: itemValue,
        })
        }
    }
    }>
    {Object.keys(this.state.cities).map(key => {
        return <Picker.Item label={this.state.cities[key].isim} value={this.state.cities[key].sehir_no} />
    })}
    </Picker>
</View>
```